# How to access elements of page after login selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I can successfully login using the selenium web driver, but I don't know how to access the frame on the next page. I have tried setting the new frame, but it does not find that element because I think it is looking through the elements on the login page instead of the page after. This is the url after the login is successful. `https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Classes/Classwork`

[Path of frame on page AFTER login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cKFV.png)

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
url = "https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fHomeAccess"
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('LogOnDetails_UserName')
browser.find_element_by_id('LogOnDetails_Password')
browser.find_element_by_id('LogOnDetails_UserName').clear()
browser.find_element_by_id('LogOnDetails_Password').clear()
browser.find_element_by_id('LogOnDetails_UserName').send_keys('******')
browser.find_element_by_id('LogOnDetails_Password').send_keys('******')
```

This is all on  the page after the login

```
frame = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sg-legacy-iframe"]') //prints no such element found
browser.switch_to_frame(frame)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SignInSectionContainer"]/div[2]/button').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait for frame to appear:

```
frame = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'sg-legacy-iframe')))
```

Comment: I am getting an error http://puu.sh/oHUyF/81e555063f.png. But this time it's not the no such element error!!

Comment: Are you still trying to switch to the frame? (i.e. `browser.switch_to_frame(frame)`) You don't need to, as name suggests `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` already does it, see https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html: "An expectation for checking whether the given frame is available to switch to. If the frame is available it switches the given driver to the specified frame."

Answer (score 0):

After performing click on Login please wait for some time to load the page.

```
  You can use WebDriverWait for waiting for required element

  if above one fails generally in java in will go for Thread.sleep(5000);
```

As per provided  HTML code you can try switching to frames by other locators if id fails

```
   driver.switchTo().frame("sg-legacy-iframe"); //by providing id

  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='MainContent/iframe"))); //by providing xpath
```

Thank You,
Murali